# How can create a nested directory?

Tags: python, linux

What is to check if the directory a file is going to be written to exists, and if not, create the directory using Python? Here is what I tried:

```
import os

file_path = "/downloads/text.txt"
directory = os.path.dirname(file_path)

try:
    os.stat(directory)
except:
    os.mkdir(directory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one for directory:

```py
os.path.isdir(file_path)
```

To check if a file exist, try this:

```py
os.path.isfile(file_path)
```